# jQuery/Ajax - Live update

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a cron job running searching Twitter every 5 minutes, each 5 minutes the results of the search are written to a database.

Im surfacing the twitter search results in a simple HTML list.

What I would like to do is load any new search results at the top of this list every 5 minutes.

Can any suggest how I might go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at the [jQuery Timers Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/timers)

Here's a [tutorial](http://www.thatagency.com/design-studio-blog/2009/01/refreshing-an-element-at-a-set-time-interval-using-jquery-and-a-sprinkle-of-ajax/) with [demo page](http://www.thatagency.com/design-studio-blog/examples/simple-page-element-refresh/) to get you started

Answer (score 1):

I would write a function to update the HTML list, then use `setInterval` to run it:

```
function updateList(){ /*magic*/ }

setInterval(updateList,1000*5*60); //Run updateList every 5 minutes
```

[MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536749(VS.85).aspx)

[Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval)

Comment: Also I would set the first call to `updateList` based on when the last cron job was run - so if it was ran 30 seconds ago when the page was first called set the first call to be in `300 - 30` seconds.

You will then want another `setInterval` call to be at the bottom of `updateList`:- `function updateList() { /* magic */ setInterval('updateList()', 1000*5*60); }`

Comment: I'm guessing if the first 30 seconds were critical, you wouldn't update it every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simple use a window.setInterval() with a 5 minute interval to call the AJAX function every 5 minutes to get the new results?

Or you can also do it without any JavaScript. Just insert the HTML into an iframe and use the refresh meta in this iframe:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3000; URL=http://www.example.com/twitterlist">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `since_id` paramter - http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-Search-API-Method%3A-search